# Creating a report with specific individuals

Tags: contacts, civireport, contributions, reports

I have an excel document of donors that are already in the system but I want to make a specific contribution report for them to see who hasn't given in the last 36 months.

I do not want to import this CSV to avoid duplicating contacts.

All I want to do is create a contribution report with specific contacts filtering their giving.

Comment: could you give more details about what we've already done/tried and how you're not successful?

Answer (score 0):

You can do an import of just the name/email, and use a Matching Rule that ensures you do not create duplicates, and on the last step of the import you can then add them to a new Group.

This should mean you can
a/ then find all contacts in that Group and build your report
b/ run a more liberal dedupe rule on just that Group to pick up any duplicates that might have snuck in due to name differences eg Tom v Thomas (eg by setting First Name in the dedupe rule to only be 1 character long)